# Подскажите с датой

Tags: дата, php

Подскажите как сделать время в таком формате (22:00), время Московское
Вот есть данный код

```
$date = date_create();
echo date_timestamp_get($date);
```

Кто подскажите ?!

Comment: $date = date_create();
echo date_format($date, 'H:i');

Но как сделать московскую дату ?!

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('H:i');

$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow');
$date->setTimeZone($tz);
echo $date->format('H:i');
```

http://codepad.org/qvxWb956

Comment: Вроде-бы Europe/Moscow показывает на 1 час меньше...
Если поставить Europe/Samara -- то вроде бы показывает как положено.

Comment: date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Moscow");
$time = time();
echo date("H:i", $time);
У меня вот так работает

Answer (score 0):

```
date("G:i")
```